# Retrofit: Parse unicode characters in json

Tags: android, unicode, gson, retrofit, unicode-string

I have some UNICODE characters in my response like this:

```
"city": "Bel\\u00e9m"
```

and it is parsed like this:

```
city =  "Bel\u00e9m"
```

But i expect it to be:

```
city = "Belém"
```

What is going wrong here and what should i do to have a properly parsed unicode character in my response?

Answer (score 0):

try this out,

```
Html.fromHtml(city.replaceAll("\\","\"));
```

Comment: I'm doing this in my view, but it shows it like this: `"Bel\u00e9m"`. because it gets two `\\` character

Comment: yes for that replace "\\" to "\" first then pass it to html

Comment: I know this, but it is not a proper way to handle unicode characters. I want a general and standard solution

Comment: this solution causes all \\ characters to be \. so if we have some backslash characters that we want to show to user it will be scaped.

Comment: yup but if you just what to change the first "\\" you can use replace instead of replaceall

Answer (score 0):

String auto convert unicode characters to letters.
So save your response to a `string` variable and then make **`JSON`** from that string object.

```
String myString = "city": your json response;
```

then make json object from `myString`

```
JSonObject obj = new JSonObject(myString);
```

may it help you.